# Output built dev files on Next.js project

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

I want Next.js to output built files so that local proxy can map them. How to let Next.js output dev files?

I once tried [`devServer.writeToDisk`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverwritetodisk-), but it didn't work because [next.js doesn't use Webpack dev server](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/2281#issuecomment-309258531).

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.devServer = { writeToDisk: true };
    return config;
  },
};
```

Comment: Check this out: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export

Comment: @Dominik Thanks but I want those files to be efficiently watched and built

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Next is a static site generator and you running those commands means you’re building them as artefacts. And on top of that if you like, add those files into git.

Comment: I meant `next dev`